# Processing Images from a directory using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have about 200- 400 pictures in a folder to be processed. I am trying to use python to write a sort of script to process these images. The image output are changing but there are some logic error which i am aware of but no idea to amend. These are the two files i have so far

test2 and resize are 2 .py files that i have created. test2.py will be calling resize.py it will resize images that are in the directory

**test2.py**

```
import glob
import cv2


from resize import process


for image_file in glob.iglob('/home/winowa/Desktop/Intern101/fisherFace/test/*.jpg'):
        process(image_file)
```

**resize.py**

```
import cv2

def process(filename):

    image = cv2.imread(filename)


    print image.shape

    r = 100.0 / image.shape[1]
    dim = (100, int(image.shape[0] *r))

    imageresized = cv2.resize(image,(300,300),dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    for i in range(19):
        cv2.imwrite( 'imageresized_{}.jpg'.format(i) ,imageresized )
        print 'imageresized_{}.jpg'.format(i)
```

i am aware that after entering resize.py it will loop19 times before going to the 2nd round of test2.py. I am trying to correct the program to move on to the next image and will output images name as imageresized1.jpg,imageresized2.jpg and so on. Now images are the right name but wrong images. Only one image is being prcessed due to the for loop. range(19) are 19 images in my folder

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Micka i needed to link two python script to run a resize of 300x300 on all the images in a paticular folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

**test2.py**

```
import glob
import cv2

from resize import process

for (i,image_file) in enumerate(glob.iglob('/home/winowa/Desktop/Intern101/fisherFace/test/*.jpg')):
        process(image_file, i)
```

**resize.py**

```
import cv2

def process(filename, key):

    image = cv2.imread(filename)

    print image.shape

    r = 100.0 / image.shape[1]
    dim = (100, int(image.shape[0] *r))

    imageresized = cv2.resize(image,(300,300),dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cv2.imwrite( 'imageresized_{}.jpg'.format(key) ,imageresized )
    print 'imageresized_{}.jpg'.format(key)
```

This assumes that you only want to write a single file for each call to `process` and that your "19 files" will be the files matched by `glob`.

Comment: exactly what i needed. thanks. can you elaborate a little more on what you edit and why you did that. it will help me that i am still new in python. thanks :)